# Hadoop - CPU intensive application - Small data

Tags: performance, hadoop, cpu

Is *Hadoop* a proper solution for jobs that are CPU intensive and need to process a small file of around 500 MB? I have read that *Hadoop* is aimed to process the so called *Big Data*, and I wonder how it performs with a small amount of data (but a CPU intensive workload).

I would mainly like to know if a better approach for this scenario exists or instead I should stick to *Hadoop*.

Comment: If you can frame your processing task into a "MapReduce" algorithm, then Hadoop may be fine. Otherwise you should first try to find algorithms to parallelize your task. Second, choose any tool that fits.

Comment: I actually have a Hadoop solution for my application, but I am looking for a better approach (if exists).

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is a distributed computing framework proposing a MapReduce engine. If you can express your parallelizable cpu intensive application with this paradigm (or any other supported by Hadoop modules), you may take advantage of Hadoop. 
A classical example of Hadoop computations is the calculation of Pi, which doesn't need any input data. As you'll see [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/two-quadrillionth-bit-0-467.html), yahoo managed to determine the two quadrillonth digit of pi thanks to Hadoop.

However, Hadoop is indeed specialized for *Big Data* in the sense that it was developped for this aim. For instance, you dispose of a file system designed to contain huge files. These huge files are chunked into a lot of blocks accross a large number of nodes. In order to ensure your data integrity, each block has to be replicated to other nodes.

To conclude, I'd say that if you already dispose of an Hadoop cluster, you may want to take advantage of it. 
If that's not the case, and while I can't recommand anything since I have no idea what exactly is your need, I think you can find more light weights frameworks than Hadoop.

Comment: I am already using a Hadoop approach in Amazon's Elastic MapReduce infrastructure, but as I am in the early stage of a project, it is important for me to choose the correct way to go. My aim is to generate a scalable infrastructure that allows the system to concentrate its resources mostly on compute time instead of  in deployment and distribution time.

Answer (score 1):

Well a lot of companies are moving to Spark, and I personally believe it's the future of parallel processing.

It sounds like what you want to do is use many CPUs possibly on many nodes.  For this you should use a Scalable Language especially designed for this problem - in other words Scala.  Using Scala with Spark is much much easier and much much faster than hadoop.

If you don't have access to a cluster, it can be an idea to use Spark anyway so that you can use it in future more easily.  Or just use `.par` in Scala and that will paralellalize your code and use all the CPUs on your local machine.

Finally Hadoop is indeed intended for Big Data, whereas Spark is really just a very general MPP framework.

Comment: I actually want to read the data from a small file (~500 MB) and make some CPU-intensive calculation with each line. I am already using Hadoop on an Amazon Elastic MapReduce cluster, but I am afraid the deployment and distribution overhead might exceed the acceptable rate of time for my purposes. If, as you say, Spark is a much faster approach than Hadoop, I will give a serious thought on using it for my project. I have also read about the Storm project, but since my application does not need real time processing at all, I guess it might be useless for my purposes.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question. Spark may be a nice thing, Scala either, but the question was very specific!

Comment: @Frunsi The question asks "Is Hadoop a proper solution for ..." my answer is basically "Yes, but spark would be a better solution" how is that not answering the question?!?! It's clearly an open ended question with a slightly open ended answer. Please retract your downvote.

Comment: And do not forget that "MapReduce" is just one algorithm, and it is not the end, it never was, well, it ever was just a quick & dirty archtitecture, solving an actual algorithm. However, MapReduce never was, and never will be the solution to your problems. Even google recognized that lately :D

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly the type of computing issue that we do for Data Normalization. This is a need for parallel processing on cheap hardware and software with ease of use instead of going through all the special programming for traditional parallel processing. Hadoop was born of hugely distributed data replication with relatively simple computations. Indeed, the test application still being distributed, WordCount, is numbingly simplistic. This is because the genesis of Hadoop was do handle the tremendous amount of data and concurrent processing for search, with the "Big Data" analytics movement added on afterwards to try to find a more general purpose business use case. Thus, Hadoop as described in its common form is not targeted to the use case you and we have. But, Hadoop does offer the key capabilities of cheap, easy, fast parallel processing of "Small Data" with custom and complicated programming logic.

In fact, we have tuned Hadoop to do just this. We have a special built hardware environment, PSIKLOPS, that is powerful for small cluster (1-10) nodes with enough power at low cost for run 4-20 parallel jobs. We will be showcasing this in a series of web casts by Inside Analysis titled Tech Lab in conjunction with Cloudera for the first series, coming in early Aug 2014.   We see this capability as being a key enabler for people like you.  PSIKLOPS is not required to use Hadoop in the manner we will showcase, but it is being configured to maximize ease of use to launch multiple concurrent containers of custom Java.